# How to get a user from post table when using hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I am pretty new to Laravel and i have been stuck with this problem for quite a while now ,I face a problem when trying to get a user name through post table using hasMany relationship. Hope the added code helps to understand the problem better. Thank you

```
   public function main_page(){

        $post= Post::all();


        return view('main' , compact('post') );
    }
```

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')

    @foreach ($post as $p)


    {{$p->users()->name }}

    @endforeach

@endsection
```

```
    public function users(){

        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

I expect that author's name of the post would be displayed ,but it is not the case. I get an error:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

My posts table looks like this:

```
id
user_id
title
content
created_at
updated_at
```

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but I can tell you that `@foreach ($post as $p)`  is evidently not producing what you expect.  Somewhere, `$p` has to be initialized as an object.  It apparently is not being initialized, because the error message is telling you that `$p` is not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning the user in the relation in your **Post** model, try this:

```
public function user(){

   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The name of the function should be `user`, on singular as @Ross Wilson suggested.

In your view you could do this:

```
@section('content')
    @foreach ($post as $p)
    {{$p->user->name }}
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

```
{{ $p->users->name }}
```

If you don't want to add clauses to your relationships then you can access it by treating it as a property.

I would suggest renaming your `users()` method to `user()` as a `belongsTo` relationship with will only ever return a single model. If you do that then you'll need to change the code in your blade file to `$p->user->name`.

Comment: Once i write {{$p->users->name }} i get another error stating: App\Post::users must return a relationship instance.

Answer (score 0):

try 
Blade view

```
@foreach ($post as $p)

{{$p->user->name }}

@endforeach
```

Controller

```
  public function main_page(){

    $post= Post::with('user')->latest()->get();


    return view('main' , compact('post') );
}
```

Model `post`

```
  public function user(){

    $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```