# How can I get the user name who posted the post (laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm try to get the user name who create the post witch is ***(Problem model)***, I do not know what is wrong I have try [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in laravel documentation and I have check these [Questions 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319161/how-to-get-a-user-from-post-table-when-using-hasmany-relationship)  [Questions 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596231/how-can-i-retreive-the-user-who-posted-the-post) and still get null or `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object` if I use `dd( $problem->user->name);`

**I use laravel 5.8**

## ProblemsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Problems ;
use App\Rules\Checkbox;
use Validator;
[...]
 public function index() 
    {
        //$users_row_num = User::count();
       // $problems_row_num = Problems::count();

       $problems = Problems::all();
       

        foreach ($problems as $problem) {
        /* Here should get name to send with view but I get null
         * if I try  $problem->user->name I get Trying to get property 'name' of non-object because user is null 
         */
            dd( $problem->user); 
        }
       
        return view('problems.index', [
            'problems' => $problem,
            'user_numder' => $users_row_num,
            'problem_number' => $problems_row_num,
        ]);
    }

[...]
```

## Problems.php (model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Problems extends Model
{
    
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

## Usre.php (model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
[...]

 public function problem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Problems');
    }

[...]
}
```

## index.blade.php

```
 @foreach ($problems as $problem)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $problem->accountNumber }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $problem->accountName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $problem->accountEmail }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $problem->date }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $problem->problem }}</td>
                               
                                <td>{{ $problem->addedBy }}</td> <!-- Here I get user id (foreign key) I want to get name of that user -->
                               
                                <td>{{ $problem->comment }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $problem->solvedBy }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $problem->solved }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $problem->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
                                <td class="text-right"> </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

## Problem table

```
[...]
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('problems', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('accountNumber');
            $table->string('accountName');
            $table->string('accountEmail');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->longText('problem');
            $table->bigInteger('addedBy')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->longText('comment')->nullable();
            $table->string('solvedBy')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('solved');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
[...]
```

## ForingkeyAddedby migration

```
[...]
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('problems', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('addedBy')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('CASCADE');

        });
    }
[...]
```

**I want to use `$problem->user->name` to get name of user who create post to display it in table**

**Please help.**

***THANKS ALL.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **User** model is looking for a `user_id` field within the problems table to make the relationship work.  Laravel automatically creates the relationship using a snake case for the model relationship using the name of the model + '_id'.

If you change your foreign key on the problems table to `user_id` instead of `addedBy`, this will work as it stands.

Or, if you wish to keep the `addedBy` key, you will need to tell Laravel that you are using a non-standard key.  So, on your **User** model:

```
public function problem()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Problems', 'addedBy');
}
```

should do the trick.  See the [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Unfortunately, it also looks like you haven't defined the actual FK on the table perhaps.  Before the `foreign` designation, I would expect to see something like:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Or if using a newer version of Laravel:

```
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
 $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

The [docs for migrations are here for V6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations).

Comment: I have try this ```return $this->hasMany('App\Problems', ''addedBy');``` but still have same problem even if I use ```$problem->user``` I get null that mean I cannot get user at all.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo - I imagine this failed due to the extra `'`  This won't work without the actual declaration of the FK on the database though.  You must enter something like `$table->unsignedBigInteger('addedBy');` above the `foreign()` line if you want to do this.  Strongly recommend using `user_id` instead to keep aligned with convention - it makes it easier.  You will continue to get the null User unless you correctly add the key to the Database.

Comment: Thank you my dear I have change name of FK to user_id as you say. It's work